# pgn2ltx -- command not found

Tags: latex, chess

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and found the program pgn2ltx (http://pgn2ltx.sourceforge.net/) to convert pgn-files to LaTex. I unzipped the files in a folder with the same name and created a binary file with the command `make pgn2ltx`. When I try to run it from the command line I get `pgn2ltx: command not found`. Now I don't know how to proceed from here. Regards, Michael

Comment: Is the binary file in the same directory as you are currently in?  Did you run `make install` or did you just run the make command to build the binary?

Comment: I just used `make pgn2ltx` and when I press enter `g++ pgn2ltx.cpp -o pgn2ltx` shows in the next line. The command `make install pgn2ltx` gives `make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ran the `make` command it built the binary, but it didn't install it.  There doesn't appear to *be* an install option for your program, so you need to reference the executable by referring to it with `./pgn2ltx` when you are in the directory where you built the software.

The other solution is to copy the compiled executable into `/home/$USER/bin` (creating the folder first if it doesn't exist), and then add that directory to your `$PATH` with `export PATH="/home/$USER/bin:$PATH"` either directly on the command line yourself, or as part of your `~/.bashrc` file so the changes are persistent.  From there, then, the executable will be recognized as a valid program when you try and execute the software with just `pgn2ltx` on the command line directly.